# why a manyToMany join table does not insert

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I use all the default table name and column names, so I didn't add a jointable (actually I tried with jointable). Bidirectional, only one of the two Entities has a mappedBy.

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<House> houses;


@Entity
public class House extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "houses")
    Set<User> users;
```

Should be simple enough, except that the hibernate does not insert jointable after running test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoSmApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws IOException {
        House p =new House();
        Set us = new HashSet<>();
        User u = userRepository.findOne(1L);
        us.add(u);
        p.setUsers(us);
        houseRepository.save(p);
    }
```

The console only has one "insert":

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_5_0_, user0_.name as name2_5_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into house (random) values (?)
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Comment: @Cepr0 sorry ho, I tried your method, but no luck. Actually when I got my hands free I'll step into to compare what has changed. There is another place in our project that uses exactly the same manytomany, but that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When we are using [bidirectional](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional) associations we have to provide 'helper' methods to preserve synchronicity between both sides, for example:

```java
public House addUsers(User... users) {
  Stream.of(users).forEach(user -> {
    user.getHouses().add(this);
    this.users.add(user);
  });
  return this;
}
```

More other we have to set the `cascade` property of the `@ManyToMany` annotation at least to `MERGE` to tell Hibernate to update nested objects as well, when we update the 'parent' entity:

```java
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "houses", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private final Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Then we can get the right result:

```java
List<User> users = userRepo.save(Arrays.asList(
    new User("user1"),
    new User("user2"),
    new User("user3")
));

List<House> houses = houseRepo.save(Arrays.asList(
    new House("address1"),
    new House("address2")
));

houses.get(0).addUsers(users.get(0), users.get(1));
houses.get(1).addUsers(users.get(1), users.get(2));

houseRepo.save(houses);
```